# CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI always return empty

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, calllog, android-dialer

I have facing very critical issue.  I developing call log related apps but when i getting call log from content provider i am not able to find CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI. It's always returning empty. I am using VIVO 1917( Funtouch OS_10)

```
 public static void loadData(Context context) {
    mainList = new ArrayList<>();
    
    String projection[] = {"_id", CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.DATE, CallLog.Calls.DURATION, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI, CallLog.Calls.TYPE, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME};
    ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    if (cursor == null) {
        Log.d("CALLLOG", "cursor is null");
        return;
    }

    if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("CALLLOG", "cursor size is 0");
        return;
    }

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        CallLogInfo callLogInfo = new CallLogInfo();
        callLogInfo.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME)));
        callLogInfo.setNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)));
        callLogInfo.setCallType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));
        callLogInfo.setDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE)));
        callLogInfo.setDuration(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION)));
        String ss = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_PHOTO_URI));

        Log.e("TAG", "  recent calls " + ss);
        mainList.add(callLogInfo);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation from Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls#CACHED_PHOTO_URI):

> CACHED_PHOTO_URI Added in API level 23
>
> The cached photo URI of the picture associated with the phone number,
> if it exists.
>
> This value is typically filled in by the dialer app for the caching
> purpose, so **it's not guaranteed to be present**, and may not be current
> if the contact information associated with this number has changed.

This means depending on the Dialer App which differs from manufacturers this value may not be present.

You might have a better chance by looking up the number/name in the contacts yourself and get an image this way.

Comment: that means i am filtering recent call with contacts and get image uri?

Comment: @Samset yeah, you could probably use this https://github.com/tamir7/Contacts to make it a bit easier since the contacts api seems a bit complicated

Comment: thanks @JensV. I have one another issue can u help me if possible i integrating conference call code but in VIVO incallService not working for conference call. All other device are working fine.

Comment: @Samset that's a separate question. One which I can't help you with anyways

Comment: NOTE: On Xaiomi you must fetch the image from the contact